# What's the best way to push code updates to a server while using Python?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new at coding, and Python in general.  I've written a python script that scrapes data from several sites and saves it to a sqlite3 db.  I put it on a digital ocean VPS and it runs several times a day using cron.  I currently use dropbox to sync files from the computer I'm doing the coding on to the server and it seems to be working okay but it just feels like I'm doing things incorrectly.

**What is the proper way to take code after I've made an update and sync it over to my server?

What's the proper term for this?**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: This is called deployment. There are loads of ways to do it, but probably the easiest is to use your version control system (you *are* using version control, of course). There are plenty of blog posts around showing you how to do it with git.

Comment: Thank you both.  I've set up a remote repo on my server with git and set up hooks to move the files to a production location.  I definitely feel A LOT safer now when I deploy!

Answer (score 1):

You should use git.

Commit your code to git repo and update on your VPS.

You could add the update logic into your crontab script.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up setting up a git repo and I'm feeling a lot better about how my server is set up now.

Answer (score 0):

I know these options:

- Git (Already mentioned)
- (S)FTP (Better if you work on the code alone)
- Samba Share (Also better if you're alone)